# How I can filter out emails from specific domains?

Tags: command-line, email, text-processing

From a file, containing one email per line, I have tried to remove the domains in the emails using this command:

```
grep -viwE "(gmail.com|hotmail|yahoo|aol|rediffmail.com|msn|outlook|inbox.com|icloud.com|mail.com|zoho.com|yandex|live.)" * > dest.txt
```

It is however also removing the emails containing particular terms, similar to what I have given in the brackets.
Say for example the email:  `example@gmail.com` & `examplegmail.com@ff.com`
The email `example@gmail.com` should get deleted, but the another emails should not. The above command is deleting both the instances which is not good. How I can avoid it?

Additional complication is that possibly encoding errors will occur.

Comment: Try adding the `@` character before the opening parenthesis in your pattern.

Comment: How is your input formatted? One email address per line? Space separated list, comma separated list, etc?

Comment: @ByteCommander Yes single line single email.

Comment: @JacobVlijm It is nice. But I want to delete only the lines containing specific domains in them. You can check in the `grep` command I have mentioned some domains whose emails I need to eliminate. I want the lines to be deleted containing those domains in them.

Comment: But why should `examplegmail.com@gmail.com` not be deleted?

Comment: @JacobVlijm no... oops question editing .. may framed wrongly...

Comment: `grep -viP '@.*\b(gmail.com|hotmail|yahoo|aol|rediffmail.com......)\b'`

Answer (score 1):

In a tiny script:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys

# list domains to be removed
rm = [
    'gmail.com', 'hotmail', 'yahoo', 'aol', 'rediffmail.com',
    'msn', 'outlook', 'inbox.com', 'icloud.com', 'mail.com',
    'zoho.com', 'yandex', 'live'
    ]
# read the file per line
for l in open(sys.argv[1]):
    # see if not any of the @domains is in the line
    if not any([d in l for d in ["@"+d for d in rm]]):
        # then print the line
        print(l.strip())
```

#### To use

- Copy the script into an empty file as `filter_doms.py`
- Run it with the input file as argument:

  ```
  python3 /path/to/filter_doms.py input_file > output_file
  ```

#### Explanation

I believe the code and the comments explains itself :)

---

As requested in a comment, a version to *ignore* decoding errors:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
import codecs

rm = [
    'gmail.com', 'hotmail', 'yahoo', 'aol', 'rediffmail.com',
    'msn', 'outlook', 'inbox.com', 'icloud.com', 'mail.com',
    'zoho.com', 'yandex', 'live'
    ]

with codecs.open(sys.argv[1], "r", encoding="utf-8", errors="ignore") as read:
    for l in read:
        if not any([d in l for d in ["@"+d for d in rm]]):
            print(l.strip())
```

Usage is exactly similar

Comment: may I know the meaning of this error: ` Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "RemaovedomainGMAIL.py", line 13, in <module>
    for l in open(file):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/codecs.py", line 321, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc4 in position 4245: invalid continuation byte
`

Comment: @JafferWilson What is the origin of the file? Obviously an encoding error.

Comment: Its a text file. also the code leaves space in between the two lines which not good. How I can resolve those encoding error. Kindly suggest me.

Comment: @JafferWilson added version, ignoring decoding errors.

Comment: Is it possibe Jacob, to eliminate or delete those lines which are not in UTF-8 encoded, so that I get a pure file with UTF-8 encoded charcters/text only?

Comment: Hi @JafferWilson, according to this: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html#the-unicode-type `ignore` should leave out errors, I replaced `replace` by `ignore`. That should do the job, but I am curious if that delivers the right result?

Comment: Yes it has...:)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53446/discussion-between-jaffer-wilson-and-jacob-vlijm).

Comment: Hi @JafferWilson I noticed you unaccepted. Anything wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `grep`'s `-f` option something like this.

```
grep -vhf patternfile file file1
```

Put all your pattern in `patternfile` line by line like

```
@gmail.com
@hotmail
@yahoo
@aol
@rediffmail.com
..
```

The option `-h` is supress prefixing filename when more than one file is given in input.